# Meaning of 16 in raw DAO16 CD-writing mode

Tags: cd-burning, cd-r

Can anybody explain why is there `16` in the `DAO16` (P and Q subchannels) writing mode's name?

It should be 24 (one subchannel consists of 96 bits = 12 bytes) or 22 (if Q subchannel's CRC (16 bits = 2 bytes) is not written) as in DAO96 (P-W subchannels) -> DAO94.

Information on raw DAO-modes:

1. http://www.cdrfaq.org/faq03.html#S3-51
2. http://www.cdrfaq.org/faq02.html#S2-43-5

Comment: Where did you hear of such a thing?  DAO is just Disk At Once, meaning you write the whole disk in one go from start to finish.

Answer (score 0):

The "16" refers to 16 bytes of sub-channel data (the sum of P and Q).  Where do you see that it's not 16 bytes?

Comment: Ok, if it is so, then what will be DAO96?